# panel data in R

Tags: r, panel, time-series, regression

I have been working with `zoo` to utilize lagging and differencing for my time series data.  I am not working with a panel data set that consists of firm and date.  It becomes very cumbersome to lag each firm individually and then merge the results.  Are there any good packages that work with panel data in R? I am aware of `plm` currently.  Others? `plm` has the  weird issue that the `lag` order (ie -1 vs +1) is exactly opposite of `zoo` and `ts` and thus I foresee headaches ahead.  Any packages that anyone like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ddply` function, in the `plyr` package,
usually makes this kind of operation painless
(but it can be slow on large datasets).

```
# Sample data
library(quantmod)
d <- NULL
for(s in c("^GSPC","^N225")) {
  tmp <- getSymbols(s,auto.assign=FALSE)
  tmp <- Ad(tmp)
  names(tmp) <- "price"
  tmp <- data.frame( date=index(tmp), id=s, price=coredata(tmp) )
  d[[s]] <- tmp
}
d <- do.call(rbind, d)
rownames(d) <- NULL

# Sample computations: lag the prices and compute the logarithmic returns
library(plyr)
d <- ddply(
  d, "id", 
  mutate,
  previous_price = lag(xts(price,date)),
  log_return = log(price / previous_price)
)
```

Comment: ddply can be quite fast!  You can use its parallel computing functionality with
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)
And adding the .parallel=T argument
You can track progress with .progress="text"

Comment: @EtienneLow-Décarie: What can be slow (and I think this part cannot be parallelized)
is splitting the data.frame into many smaller data.frames.
My situation looked like this
(1 million rows, 100,000 groups with 1 to 1000 elements in each,
with a user-defined function instead of `max`):
`d <- data.frame(g=round(1e5*rlnorm(1e6)),x=runif(1e6));
d1 <- ddply(d,"g",summarize,max(x))`.
The following is much faster:
`d2 <- sqldf("SELECT g, MAX(x) FROM d GROUP BY g")`.

Comment: could you please describe more about the parallel computing infrastructure?

Comment: i am currently using plyr to do this stuff and it is painfully slow because i have a large data set (about 4 mil rows, 1000 groups)